# Vista Recycle Bin Maximum Size

Tags: windows-vista, vbscript, batch-file, cmd, recycle-bin

Does anyone know how to set the Maximum Size of the Recycle Bin via script?
Whether its written in batch or vbs or just a reg file?
I've been exploring this idea for the last few days, and can't get an answer. Maybe someone here knows how. I'm wanting to add it to my Vista Cleanup Script =)

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of the Recycle Bin for each drive is stored under this key:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\BitBucket\Volume\
```

There's a subkey with the GUID of each mounted volume. This GUID can be found with the MOUNTVOL command, or programmatically with GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint().

You can just change the size value and it will be picked up by Explorer the next time something is deleted (i.e. you don't need to notify the shell about the change).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something code *should* be able to do, therefore there probably isn't a way. Seems like something Raymond Chen would blog about.

Why would you want to do that?

Comment: He wants to add it to his Vista cleanup script! ;)